# Why it's so slow when a wcf client connects to the service?

Tags: wcf, performance

I met a performance issue when using the WCF service.

Here's the story:

1. I wrote a self-hosted WCF service which is hosted by a console application;
2. I wrote a simple client to consume the service;
3. After the WCF service is running, it takes over 15 seconds for the client to create connection with the service.

The WCF service is extremely simple just something like "Hello World". Is this normal?

Comment: Are you hosting the WCF Service in Internet Information Services?

Comment: No, it's hosted by a console application

Answer (score 3):

One way could be to add your own [warmup](http://programmerramblings.blogspot.com/2008/09/aspnet-site-warmup.html) script; a script that calls your service on initial load.

Though, [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/fb84cbf3-c72a-4b28-a0ea-d549f9bc75e3/) might help you, usually, the first access to the service is slow, but the consecutive accesses would be within a sec or two.

The first slow response is related to the JIT compilation of the service assemblies; which means its normal.

Alternatively, you may want to [Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx?pr=blog) you app. Also you may would like to checkout this [article](http://izlooite.blogspot.com/2010/10/aspnet-slow-on-first-access.html) that I wrote some time back.

Answer (score 1):

We experiences the same, I figured out that it is the client that sleeps up to 14 seconds before actually opening the TCP connection.

A simple call to

```
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
```

solved this.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751883.aspx

If you host on IIS, that takes a while to start up no matter what.

Comment: I didn't design any serialization/deserialization methods inside, just return an integer value from the service. And the service is hosted within a console application.

Comment: WCF has it's own contract [de]serializers -- even if you're just sending basic data types. Having said that, WCF's first startup has been slow on my systems no matter what I've tried. I use IIS hosting, so just turn off periodic App Pool cycling.