# How to speed up start up performance of WCF client

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, xml-serialization, service-reference

I have implemented a simple standalone WCF service with a basicHttpBinding binding.
I created a client and generated the client stub code by using Add Service Reference.
The first time the client call the service it takes at least 15 seconds before the server sees the request. From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040986/why-its-so-slow-when-a-wcf-client-connects-to-the-service) it seems that it is due to JIT generation of serialization code.
I tried to pre-generate the code as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751883.aspx) using

```
svcutil.exe /t:xmlSerializer <assemblyPath>
```

on my complied client exe but code but got the following error: No service contract in the assembly has an operation with `XmlSerializerOperationBehavior`.

Comment: Did you mark your service class with `XmlSerializerOperationBehavior`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should note, that if you are using precompiled code, you will lose performance, as precompiled code doesn't use any platform-specific, it just compiles a "normal" code.

On other hand, JIT really get some performance hit at the first-time compilation (for the proxy-class creation), but it really works better at futher requests.

So I suggest you to check the initialization code for your service **and client** - may be, you can optimize it (15 seconds means that you are creating much number of objects from various assemblies).

Try to use some [Lazy classes](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/10/04/laziness-in-c-4-0-lazyt/)

Comment: @VMAfm - I don't think this is a problem with the server. The delay occurs every time I start the client. The client calls the service mulitple times - this first one is always slow but subsequent calls are very quick. It desn't matter what the operation does - even if it just returns a short string the first call after the client starts is slow. From what I understand the JIT code generation is happending on the client side.

Comment: @Shane Yes, it is happening for create proxy-class. But if you wil distribute pre-compiled versio, overall performance will suffer. Check the constructor for the client - I think 15 seconds is still very much only for proxy-generation.

Comment: @VMAfm - The constructor of my Client executes quickly. The delay occurs on the first web service call. I can't affort to have a slow starup as in my usage scenario the client may only make one or two calls to the server during the lifetime of its execution.

Comment: @Shane OK then, I'll ask again: Did you mark your service class methods with `XmlSerializerOperationBehavior`?

Comment: @VMAfm - How do I apply it? I looked up the documentation and it's not an attribute.