# Performance issues with aspNetCompatibilityEnabled WCF service called from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-ajax

I have a aspNetCompatibilityEnabled WCF service in my application.

I am making ajax calls like this (Finally a direct call to WCF service)-

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '~/WCFServices/MyService.svc/GetAllFoo',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {.............//Omitted/////// },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (msg, status) {
                   .............//Omitted///////
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                   .............//Omitted///////
            }
        });
```

Everything works fine with this approach.
However, When I use this in production, and when there is high load, there are performance issues.

Using some tool, I found that /System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory+ServiceHttpHandler takes about 20 seconds.

I am not sure why this is so, and what could be done to improve the performance.
Any help/pointer is greatly appreciated.

Additional Information-
App is hosted on IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you host your application in IIS. `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` is enabled [to get benefits](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx) of IIS features for non http protocols like `net.*`.

There are several [slow down issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040986/why-its-so-slow-when-a-wcf-client-connects-to-the-service) such as IIS start up, [first call to WCF service](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/114132/WCF-First-Call-Slow).

Comment: Hi Sergio. Thanks for your response. This is not seen during IIS startup or first WCF call. This issue comes into picture when there is a good amount of load on server.